# How to install broadcom driver for Dell Inspiron 1440 in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: drivers, dell, broadcom, inspiron

I'm just install ubuntu 12.04 precise pangolin, but after installing i still need to download broadcom wireless driver.
I don't have a wired connection, can anyone please help me to install it offline?
Please help.

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless card from: lspci -nn -d 14e4:

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu unit dashboard search for "driver". You will find a additional drivers application.

[image]

And click on "Broadcom STA wireless" item. (Sometimes it may Broadcom something else.)

[image]

Then click "Activate" button just below "Close" button. To activate driver you need internet.